# Which CSS box model is implemented on iPhone/iPad Safari?

Tags: iphone, ipad, safari, css

What is the CSS box model which is implemented for iPhone/iPad Safari?

I mean the calculations for border/padding/margin with respect to the overall box width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as any other WebKit-based browser (e.g. Safari desktop, Chrome, and lots of other mobile browsers), or indeed any browser released after Internet Explorer 5.5 — the standard box model. (I.e. `width` = content width, and does not include `padding`, `border`, `margin` or anything else.)